# WPF - GetBindingExpression in PropertyChangedCallback of DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to be able to access the binding expression for the Text property of a TextBox from within a DependencyProperty on a TextBox. the value of my DependencyProperty is set in XAML. I'm calling `GetBindingExpression` in the `PropertyChangedCallback` method of my DependencyProperty, but I'm too early at this point because `GetBindingExpression` always returns null here, yet after the window fully loads it definitely returns a value (I tested using a button on screen to change the value of my DependencyProperty).

Clearly I have a load order issue here where my DependencyProperty's value is set before the Text property is bound to my view model. My question is, is there some event I can hook into to identify when the binding of the Text property is complete? Preferably without modifying the XAML of my TextBox as I have hundreds of them in the solution.

```
public class Foobar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Test", typeof(bool), typeof(Foobar),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, Foobar.TestChanged));

    private static void TestChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)o;
        var expr = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty); 
        //expr is always null here, but after the window loads it has a value
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBoxBase))]
    public static bool GetTest(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(Foobar.TestProperty);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBoxBase))]
    public static void SetTest(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(Foobar.TestProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listen to LayoutUpdated event. I think its called layout updated event. Else google it. Its a crazy little event which will be fired everytime no matter what you do ex. when loading, drawing, even when you move your mouse!

Take a look at this pseudo code:

```
private static void TestChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)o;
        // start listening
        textBox.LayoutUpdated += SomeMethod();
    }

   private static void SomeMethod(...)
   {
      // this will be called very very often
      var expr = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty); 
      if(expr != null)
      {
        // finally you got the value so stop listening
        textBox.LayoutUpdated -= SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Yep, that works perfectly, thanks! That event gets called like crazy as you say, so I'll make sure to drop the listener as soon as I've done what I need to do.

Comment: Its just a dummy event to notify you something in UI got changed. Its very important to drop listener.